# XML tags missing or skipped during xsl transformation

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, saxon, saxparser, xslt-3.0

We are performing an xsl transformation to convert hexcode entity to mdash. We also have converted all `&amp;` in xml to output as &.
This transformation happens as expected, but along with that some entities are escaped like `&apos;` converting into `'s` and similar is the case of some more entities like `&sect;` and few more entities.

And also, all tags are skipped from the xml only content is rendered in output and tags are skipped.

Ex->

Input before xsl transformation:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><name>abc<name>
```

Output after xsl transformation:-

```
abc
```

Below is the xsl used:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='3.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
  
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" use-character-maps="mdash amp" />

<xsl:character-map name="mdash">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#x2014;" string="&amp;mdash;" />
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:character-map name="amp">
  <xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="&amp;" />
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how transformation happens:-

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
InputStream xsl_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xsl_path));
StreamSource xsl_source = new StreamSource(xsl_stream, xsl_path);
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(xsl_source);
InputStream xml_inputsource = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(output_file));
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml_inputsource, output_file);
StreamResult xmlResult = new StreamResult(finalFile);
transformer.transform(xmlSource, xmlResult);
```

Is there a way to preserve xml tags in output and also unescape entites i.e. `&apos;` should remain `&apos;` after xml transformation. All entities should remain as it is after transformation.

Comment: How do you run the transformation exactly?

Comment: The input you show here is not well-formed XML and produces an error, not the result you claim.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, i have used TransformerFactory instance , and creating a transformer object from TransformerFactory reference and then calling transform function on it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I have updated the input xml now.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, sharing the transformation details in question description as well.

Comment: `tfactory.newTransformer(inputxml);` and `transformer.transform(inputxml, outputxml);` doesn't seem to make sense, are you loading the `inputxml` as the XSLT code?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, please check the updated transformer code now.

Comment: If I try to "reproduce" your issue with your sample data it already fails parsing `<name>abc<name>` as that is not even well-formed. I don't see how `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` would fail to copy nodes through. Anyway, I created a small sample project with a fixed input sample but of course the created result file has the element as well as the element text: https://github.com/martin-honnen/Saxon11JAXPTransformerTest/blob/master/result1.xml. So, basically, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, failing to copy nodes we resolved by using <xsl:template match="@* | node()">. but another issue is unescaping entity. is there a way to do it via xsl like &sect should remain &sect even after transformation.

Comment: I fail to see why you would need a template if you are using Saxon and XSLT 3. As for entity references, you can't preserve them (unless you preprocess the XML with e.g. LexEv), you can of course add character map entries for those characters you want to be output as entity references instead of as literal characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged as both `saxon` and `xalan`, which makes no sense whatsoever.

If you're using Xalan, which supports only XSLT 1.0, to process an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet that contains no templates, the result will be the string-value of the root element - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule

Comment: using saxon, hence removed xalan from the tags.

Answer (score 1):

> All entities should remain as it is after transformation

That can't be achieved because entity and character references are expanded by the XML parser before the transformation even starts.

The best you can do is to use `xsl:character-map` to convert the characters that you want to appear as entity references:

```
<xsl:character-map name="specials">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#x2014;" string="&amp;mdash;" />
  <xsl:output-character character="&#x00A7;" string="&amp;sect;" />
  .. etc ..
</xsl:character-map>
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve by outputting `&` as `&amp;`. That seems misguided. But to be honest, I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve by any of this. Telling us what output you want is one thing, but the real question is *Why?*.